# Validate field to accept either PT or FT in Access

Tags: validation, field, ms-access-2016

I have a field in MS Access called `Employee Status` which requires a validation rule to accept `PT` which is shorthand for Part Time and `FT` which is short hand for `Full Time`, I tried this `Expression Builder` but when i test it, it refuses to work

```
Like("PT")
Like("FT")
```

What expression do i need to make check for text `PT` or `FT` and validate?

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
Like("PT") OR Like("FT")
```